# How to draw circle (as radio button) in C# console applications?

Tags: c#, drawing, console-application, shapes, .net-standard

I want to know Is it possible to draw a circle in C# console? like the following picture.
[image]

I need this for creating list of radio buttons or check boxes in console application.

It should work in **.NET standard/core**.

Is it possible?

Note: Unicode chars do not show in Console correctly without changing the font but I don't want to force user for this :(
[image]

Comment: You just can use this symbol: 

Comment: @dymanoid What about empty? The console does not show Unicode characters without changing font :(

Comment: You need a Font that actually contains those symbols. The standard ones don't. Courier New has something similar, but not the same.

Comment: @Jimi Is it possible to embed a specific font for the console in .NET standard?

Comment: Possible it is. Worthy? I don't know. In Windows is common something like this: `[▪]` `[▫]`, this `□` `■` or this `○` `●`. If you want to set a non standard font, you could use [GetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getcurrentconsolefontex) and [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex). With [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) to get the Console handle. But I've never done this in .Net Standard and if you PInvoke, well, portability gone.

Comment: @Jimi, Your Unicode chars are great for me thanks :)

Comment: Good old ANSI: `( )` and `(o)`